# If more than 2 events, change cell color

Tags: fullcalendar

Im currently using eventRender to change the background color of an event's cell (month view), but I'm hoping to take it further and change the cell to another color if theres 2 or more events on that date.

Something like:

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view)

 if >2 events 
    {element.css("background-color", "orange"); }
 else
    { element.css("background-color", "red");}
```

Comment: in that case you need to count the number of events which occur on that date. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/clientEvents can help you with that. What have you researched or tried so far?

Comment: Ive been just using a var eventCounter = 0; and upping the counter when theres an event on the date. If the counter gets over 1 then i change some css, but eventRender isnt working in there.

Comment: show precisely what you did, please. And give us some sample event data, so we can reproduce the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @kingkelly Did you find any solution?
if same date have more than two events how to change the cell color?

Comment: @KhizarNayyar Nope never figured it out :(

Comment: @kingkelly kindly see the answer in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57857811/how-to-change-the-color-of-enitre-cell-if-the-same-date-has-more-than-3-events-u

Answer (score 1):

Try this one to change the back ground colour as per the different event

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
            if (event.title == 'Birthday) {
                element.css('background-color', 'red');
            }
            else if (event.title == 'Interview) {
                element.css('background-color', 'green');
            }
            else if (event.title == 'Anniversary') {
                element.css('background-color', 'Yellow');

            }
        },
```

or otherwise you can do this with in event object by add the colour.

```
events:[{
                title: 'Birthday',
                start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
                end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),
               // backgroundColor: App.getBrandColor('purple'),
                 color:'#4fc6d2'
                allDay: false
            }]
```

Comment: interesting! Im curious about how an event gets it's ID attached to it. Does each day start with the first event having id=1? The code doesnt work for me so I'm guessing my events (synched from a google calendar) dont have those IDs

Comment: not mean that each event you have title like you can add what ever  in to event object.and get in to the event render function then you can write your code.